# How to have global variables for directory paths and traverse through all file paths and include in those scripts?

Tags: python, oop, directory, environment-variables, configuration-files

I want to be able to have a file that contains variables that I can access in all my scripts within my project? I am not sure how to do this, I was also looking at environmental variables based on [this article](https://medium.com/chingu/an-introduction-to-environment-variables-and-how-to-use-them-f602f66d15fa). Not sure how to google to find what i want to find. Is there a package out there that lets you toggle between the global variables you want to use?

I have a remote server that I want to use but have to change my directories, I want to be able to refer to those specific remote paths for the script but then switch back/toggle to another set of environmental variables that contain the directory paths that are correct to my local. What is the best way for me to do this?

In my head it would look something like one variable with two paths and I switch to one or the other with just one change "local", "remote". Any resources that someone can link me to or just the name of what they use or how they do it would help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify os.environ

Let`s try it:

```
>>> import os
>>> from invoke import run
>>> os.environ['remote'] = 'server'
>>> os.environ.get('remote')
'server'
>>> run("env | grep LANG")
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
<invoke.runners.Result object at 0x1a10310>
>>> run("env | grep remote")
remote=server
<invoke.runners.Result object at 0x1a19f10>
>>>
```

And visit these links as resources:

[os.environ](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.environ)  [os.putenv](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.putenv)  [os.execve](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.execve)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but I'm actually not sure if this was what I was looking for. I think I'm looking for something more like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256964/how-to-build-config-files-in-python  https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-manage-the-configuration-in-python-4623049e841b